# Why $\log a +\ log b$ can be a rational number given $a$ and $b$ are not rational powers of 10?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am a high school student who has just started learning about the common logarithms. My teacher said that given a and b are not rational powers of 10, log a + log b can still be a rational number.

I am totally puzzled. Could you guys help me by proving it? But please do not quote some theories that are too advanced for me. Thanks very much!

Comment: Your teacher may have meant "are rational powers of 10".

Comment: "can be", not "is".  For example, $\log 2 + \log 5 = \log 10 = 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks! I got it.

Comment: Let $a = 10^{z}$ and $b = 1/a^z$ were z is irrational.  Then $\log a + \log b = z + (-z) = 0$.  Or $a = 10^{w}$ and $b = 10^{y}$ were $w + y=r$ is rational but $w$ is not and $y = r - w$ is not.  This need not *always* happen but it can *sometimes* happen.

Comment: Or... log 2 + log 5 = log 10 = 1.  d'oh.  Which is interesting to the think that if log 2 = z then log 5 = 1-z.  Really?  10^(1-z) = 10^1/10^z = 10/5 = 2.  Neat!  I never really thought of that before.  I'm *still* impressed when I can view things in new and cute ways like that.

Comment: Third thing to note:  Nothing to do with logs, but while rational + rational must be rational.  And irrational + rational must be irrational.  And irrational + irrational is *often* irrational.  It is NOTthe case that irrational + irrational MUST equal irrational.  We can always create a counter example by a = irrational,  b = rational - a = irrational, so a + b = rational.  Intuitively this seems "artificially contrived" but ... it's still valid.